# Populate dataGridView with a list inside a dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, datagridview, populate

I have a dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>>
```

After adding keys and values like this:

```
resultDic.Add(s, new List<string>());
    foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows)
    {
     resultDic[s].Add(row[3].ToString());
    }
```

I then want to display both the string values and the individual values inside the list from the dictionary. To Achieve this, I tried doing like so:

```
        dataGridView2.DataSource = Controller.GetMetaDataTables2().Select(x 
        => new { ColumnName = x.Key, Table = x.Value[0] }).ToList();
        dataGridView2.Show();
```

GetMetaDataTables2 returns a Dictionary like the one above. The problem is that index [0] obviously only gives me the first value, when I want to show the entire list. I want to iterate, but I don't know how to do that here. I'm just starting to understand the LINQ expression. Any ideas?

Grateful for any and all help!

Update: Fixed it with Markus help. I used his solution with one change. Instead of y.ToArray() I needed to simply print y. Like this:

```
   dataGridView2.DataSource = Controller.GetMetaDataTables2()
   .SelectMany(x => x.Value.Select(y => new { ColumnName = x.Key, Table = 
   y }))
   .ToArray();
   dataGridView2.Show();
```

Comment: What is your desired result? A flat table with rows like "Key A, Value A.1", "Key A, Value A.2", "Key B, Value B.1"?

Comment: Try following which uses string join  :             Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = Controller.GetMetaDataTables2.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("ColA"), y => y.Field<string>("ColB"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());var results = dict.Select(x => new { ColumnName = x.Key, Table = string.Join(",", x.Value) });

Comment: @Markus Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @jdweng Your solution gives me this error:  KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>' does not contain a definition for 'Field' and the best extension method overload 'DataRowExtensions.Field<string>(DataRow, string)' requires a receiver of type 'DataRow'. Do I need to make it so that the method GetMetaDataTables returns a DataRow?

Comment: I assumed you had DataTables. so code is looking for columns in a table.  If you have a class then replace x.Field with the property name in the class or the anonymous column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.7.2) method to flatten the list, e.g.:

```
resultDic
  .SelectMany(x => x.Value.Select(y => new { ColumnName = x.Key, Table = y.ToArray() }))
  .ToArray();
```

For

> A - "A.1", "A.2"
>   B - "B.1", "B.2"
>   C - "C.1", "C.2"

this results in

> A - A.1
>   A - A.2
>   B - B.1
>   B - B.2
>   C - C.1
>   C - C.2

In order to show it in the GridView, the code should be

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = Controller.GetMetaDataTables2()
  .SelectMany(x => x.Value.Select(y => new { ColumnName = x.Key, Table = y.ToArray() }))
  .ToArray();
dataGridView2.Show();
```

Comment: Says datasource is null in debugger.

Comment: @Heeiman I've added a sample that integrates the code with the assignment of the DataSource. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I tried. I needed to add a ")" at the end though (according to VS). Did I put it in the wrong place?

Comment: @Heeiman sorry, forgot that. I've added the parenthesis in the second line.

Comment: @Heeiman I've assigned my sample data to a DataGridView successfully. Can you check the values that are returned step by step beginning at `GetMetaDataTables2`?

Comment: Here are some screenshots of my debug and result : [Screenshots](https://imgur.com/a/vHpY4qM) As you can see, the Y variable appears to have the correct value, yet the dataGridView only displays the "Table" column, although in the correct amount. The first screenshots have slightly altered code (I was playing around), but the last one has your code.                                   Edit: It's the viewGrid to the right in the window.

Comment: @Heeiman does it work now? I had a look at the screenshots but also could not detect a difference. If it still doesn't work, I'd suggest to store each result (GetMetaDataTable2, SelectMany) in a variable and check this.